# Combine tikzpicture and tikztimingtable environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-timing

As the known about tikz-timing package, we have:

1. tikztimingtable environment

   ```
   \begin{tikztimingtable}
       Name    & hLLLLh \\
       Clock   & 20{ c } \\
       Signal  & z7D { Text } z \\
   \end{tikztimingtable}
   ```
2. tikzpicture environment

   ```
   \begin{tikzpicture}[timing/picture, thick]
       \timing at (0,2) {hH N(A) LHLHL};
       \timing [timing/slope =.25] at (0,0) 
       {HLL N(B) HHLl};
   \draw [orange,semithick]
       (A.mid) ellipse(.2 and .6)
       (B.mid) ellipse(.2 and .6);
   \draw [orange,semithick,->]
       ($(A.mid)-(0,.6)$)
       parabola[bend pos=0.5]
       ($(B.mid)+(0,.6)$);
   \end{tikzpicture}`
   ```

My question is how can I name the signals in the second picture, signalA and signalB, respectively?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The manual apparently makes no mention of a way to add names, except the method you already showed with the table. So I guess you could simply add nodes on the right. This is not really automatic, but at the moment, it's the best way I can think of.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}  
\usepackage{tikz-timing}  
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[timing/picture, thick]
    \node[anchor=base, font=\scriptsize] at (-3,2) {Signal A};
    \node[anchor=base, font=\scriptsize] at (-3,0) {Signal B};
    \timing at (0,2) {hH N(A) LHLHL};
    \timing [timing/slope =.25] at (0,0) 
    {HLL N(B) HHLl};
\draw [orange,semithick]
    (A.mid) ellipse(.2 and .6)
    (B.mid) ellipse(.2 and .6);
\draw [orange,semithick,->]
    ($(A.mid)-(0,.6)$)
    parabola[bend pos=0.5]
    ($(B.mid)+(0,.6)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```